# Cluster data using medoids (cluster centers) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe with three features as

```
library(cluster)
df <- data.frame(f1=rnorm(480,30,1),
                 f2=rnorm(480,40,0.5),
                 f3=rnorm(480,50, 2))
```

Now, I want to do clustering using `K-medoids` in two steps. In step 1, using some data from `df` I want to get medoids (cluster centers), and in step 2, I want to use obtained medoids to do clustering on remaining data. Accordingly,

```
# find medoids using some data 
sample_data <- df[1:240,]
sample_data <- scale(sample_data) # scaling features
clus_res1 <- pam(sample_data,k = 4,diss=FALSE)

# Now perform clustering using medoids obtained from above clustering
test_data <- df[241:480,]
test_data <- scale(test_data)
clus_res2 <- pam(test_data,k = 4,diss=FALSE,medoids=clus_res1$medoids)
```

With this script, I get an error message as

```
Error in pam(test_data, k = 4, diss = FALSE, medoids = clus_res1$medoids) : 
  'medoids' must be NULL or vector of 4 distinct indices in {1,2, .., n}, n=240
```

It is clear that error message is due to the input format of Medoid matrix. How can I convert this matrix to the vector as specified in the error message?

Comment: What is `coredata` ? Using the medoïds from one dataset as starting point for another dataset doesn't seem to make sense IMHO because these medoïds are just specific observations. The `medoid=` argument expect just the row number of the starting values for the medoïd search.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I have only one dataset. Here I am using some part of it  to get initial clusters. Later, I want to check how subsequent data points change with respect to initial clusters.

Comment: I am not sure that your procedure makes sense. You seem to be inserting the training stage of a supervised learning method into clustering, which is an unsupervised method. However, you can probably achieve your desired result by extracting the medoids from your initial data.frame and rbinding them to your new data.frame. Then use their row positions as the value for the medoid argument in `pam`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial medoids parameter expects *index numbers* of points in your data set. So `42,17` means to use objects 42 and 17 as initial medoids.

By the definition of medoids, you can *only* use points of your data set as medoids, *not* other vectors!

Clustering is unsupervised. No need to split your data in training/test, because there are no labels to overfit to in unsupervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in PAM the clustering center is an observation, that is you get 4 observations that each of them is a center of cluster. [Demonstration of PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids#Demonstration_of_PAM).

So if you want to try and use the same center, you need to find the observations which are closest to the observations who are the center in your train.